# Can a ravendb collection forced to be in memory?

Tags: ravendb

Can I force a ravendb collection to stay in memory so that the queries are fast. I read about aggressive caching but the documentation only talks about the request caching. If I have sharding enabled can I force all the shards to cache the collection in memory ?

Any help is appreciated,

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

RavenDB doesn't really have "Collections" in the sense you are thinking.  The only thing that collections are used for is to filter documents by their `Raven-Entity-Name` metadata.  This serves a few purposes:

- The Raven Studio UI can group things to make them easier to find.
- Indexes can use a shortcut form of `docs.EntityName` instead of having a where clause against the metadata in every index.

But that's pretty much it.  They aren't isolated on disk.  For example, when Raven indexes documents, every index considers *all* documents.  Docs get discarded quickly if they don't pass the collection filter, but they are still put through the pipeline.

You can read more about collections [here](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.0/theory/ravendb-collections).

Also - As long as you are still in a learning phase, you may want to post these style of questions on the [RavenDB Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/ravendb) instead.  You will get a much better response.  You won't get much rating on StackOverflow when you are asking non-code "can X do Y?" questions.  Come back here when you have written some code.  See the [ravendb](/questions/tagged/ravendb) tag for other questions that have been answered, and you'll get a feel for what StackOverflow is for.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do that.
RavenDB will automatically detect usage patterns and keep frequently requested documents in memory.

Comment: Thanks. But I dont want the performance hit to the query where the documents are not cached. I want to force the whole collection cached something like shark. Is there way i could do this wih raven ?